# What is the difference between function and class components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, create-react-app

I've just started learning React and i noticed that the code in the react app looks like this :

```
import Todos from './components/Todos'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (  
    <div className="App">
      <Todos/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the tutorial from which I am learning looks like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Components {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>App</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Are these two: 'function' and 'class' different ? or they are same?

Comment: You should read [this](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108)

Comment: They are two different ways to define react components. The current recommendation is to use function components with hooks. Before hooks class components were the only type of component in which you could have state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: what is the difference between functional component and class component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953840/reactjs-what-is-the-difference-between-functional-component-and-class-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're just two different ways of creating components.

That said, class components allow you to use [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle), which function components don't.

Since React 16.8, everything can be done only with function components, in a less verbose way, with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).